# Sub-domain not working

Tags: apache, subdomain

I'm pretty new to apache, so probably the solution will be obvious to you... I'm running on Debian wheezy

Here are my two file in `/etc/apache2/sites-availables`:

**amelineandraphael**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName amelineandraphael.raphaelnussbaumer.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/amelineandraphael
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/amelineandraphael>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**zoziology**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName zoziologie.raphaelnussbaumer.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/zoziologie
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/zoziologie>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

- I have added a symbolic link to `/etc/apache2/sites-enables`
- I've run `sudo a2ensite amelineandraphael` and `sudo a2ensite zoziologie`
- and restart the apache server.

The sub-domain [zoziologie.raphaelnussbaumer.com](http://zoziologie.raphaelnussbaumer.com/) is working but [amelineandraphael.raphaelnussbaumer.com](http://www.amelineandraphael.raphaelnussbaumer.com/) redirect me to the default index.html at `/var/www/`.

Here are the .htaccess of `/var/www/amelineandraphael`:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution. Although I'm not sure that's the only part of the solution:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment yet as I don't have the rep, so sorry about this being an "answer".

I'm wondering if you have a DNS "A" record for that subdomain? You may have a wildcard DNS record though, which would make this a moot point

Comment: I'm running on Debian wheezy and I do have DNS "A" for both subdomain which both point to the same IP adress (of my server VPS). And there is not wildcard DNS record. thanks for the help

Comment: You've run "sudo a2ensite amelineandraphael.raphaelnussbaumer.com" and then "sudo service apache2 reload"? (Sorry if the syntax is wrong, I'm used to Ubuntu)

Comment: I've run `sudo a2ensite amelineandraphael`, which return `Site amelineandraphael already enabled`. But `sudo a2ensite amelineandraphael.raphaelnussbaumer.com`, return `ERROR: Site amelineandraphael.raphaelnussbaumer.com does not exist!`

Comment: It looks like there's a redirect to www.amelineandraphael.raphaelnussbaumer.com. Have you checked your .htaccess in /var/www and subdirectories?

Comment: I've added it above. .htaccess of zoziologie look identical expect of the first line of PHP version. there are no .htaccess in the root /var/www.

Comment: e_i_pi is right, there is a redirect to www.amelineandraphael.raphaelnussbaumer.com, and it is not form .conf nor from .htaccess, so it has to be from the app itself. Check the [wordpress settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)