# Set up Apache with multi-domain server with OVH

Tags: apache, dns, virtualhost, redirect, ovh

My question is related to the wrong redirection of multi-domain server.

I have a VPS server on ovh.com with 2 domains names:

- `site1.com`
- `site2.com`

On OVH admin panel, I have set up the DNS zone so that each site return to the IP adress of the server with a type `A`. Each `www.siteX.com` have for target`siteX.com` with a type `CNAME`.

On the server side, I'm using Apache2 and I have created for all a conf file in `/etc/apache2/site-available/`:

- `site1.conf`
- `site2.conf`

with the same structure:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName siteX.com
    ServerAlias www.siteX.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/siteX
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I have used the command `a2ensite subX.conf` or `a2ensite siteX.conf` and `sudo service apache2 restart`

The problem I have is that `www.site2.com` is redirected to `site1.com` while `site2.com` is correct and return `site2`.

The interesting aspect is that `www.site2.com?` is correctly loading the content of site2 while keeping the `www.site2.com/?` in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Again, similar to [Sub-domain not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37477000/sub-domain-not-working), the solution was to disable the default virtualserver:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default
```

Can someone explain the reason ? How to avoid that ?

Comment: It is because 000-default contains a VirtualHost that overrides some of the directives.